# Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 data

Tags: magento2, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2. I using below code.
`php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/config.xml`

I was stuck in a position and then got error.

[image]

[image]

Here is my config.xml file.

**config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="75.124.198.248" name="menc_latest" user="menc_root" password="ers!@#$"/>
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento2" user="root" password="root"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.3.8</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key>9bcc12490f02d3fff0d089ba85ad450b</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

I am getting this error now.

[image]

Comment: As far as I see, there are certain extensions you have in your previous **magento 1** store that do not exist in your newly created **magento 2** store. You need to ignore all the tables of those non existent extensions before migration..

Comment: Can you please add your config.xml code here?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, I edited my Question. Thanks.

Comment: please DON"T share db access in `config.xml` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please replace your config.xml code with below one and change all **.xml.dist** file to **.xml** file  and try again

```
 <config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
<steps mode="settings">
    <step title="Settings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
    </step>
    <step title="Stores Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>
    <step title="EAV Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Ratings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Tier Price Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="PostProcessing Step">
        <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
    </step>
</steps>
<steps mode="delta">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
              <source>
              <database host="localhost" name="magento1-db" user="root" password=""/>
                  </source>
               <destination>
              <database host="localhost" name="magento2-db" user="root" password=""/>
              </destination>
                   <options>
              <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/map.xml</map_file>
              <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
              <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
              <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
              <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
              <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
              <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
              <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
              <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
              <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
              <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
              <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
              <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>
              <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
              <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file> 
              <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>

              <!--
              In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
              -->
              <bulk_size>100</bulk_size>
              <!--
              Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
              NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
              and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
               -->
              <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
              <source_prefix></source_prefix>
              <dest_prefix></dest_prefix>
              <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
              <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
              <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
              <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
              <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
              <edition_number>1.9.3.8</edition_number>
              <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
              <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
              <crypt_key>magento1-crypt-key</crypt_key>
               </options>
              </config>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rutvee Sojitra. I am getting error now. I edited my question. Thanks.